# How do I reduce frames with blending in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, frames, frame-rate, blending, reducing

I am trying to convert some files into ProRes. 
One fairly important part of the conversion is:

- reducing frames from 60 to 30
- blending every 2 frames into one and achieving a more fluent movement. (a simple sort of motion blur)

I have tried the `-blend` command, however it was not recognized as a command.

```
-i source.mp4 -r 30 -vcodec prores_ks -profile:v 0 Output.mov
```

How do I reduce frames with blending in ffmpeg?

Comment: Similar question on Video Production: https://video.stackexchange.com/q/16552/29892

Answer (score 6):

Simple frame dropping:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -r 30 output.mov
```

Interpolate frames with the [`minterpolate`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#minterpolate) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf minterpolate=fps=30 output.mov
```

- See link above as there are many additional options.

Interpolate frames with the [`framerate`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#framerate) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf framerate=fps=30 output.mov
```

- See link above as there are many additional options.

Comment: For me, `framerate` was literally 100x faster than `minterpolate` .

Comment: It's normal to have such speed increase @BenjaminH. One mathematically models and a function and samples each frames at points of time and other drops the frames to approximate thereof.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
ffmpeg -h
```

or

```
ffmpeg --help
```

and you'll have a short help. Please read it. :)

Try

```
ffmpeg -filters
```

and you'll have a list of available filters

Try

```
ffmpeg -help filter=name
```

and you'll have syntax and parameters for this filter

---

I already needed to do something like this, reducing framerate.
If you do

```
ffmpeg -i "input" -r outputframerate [video encoding options...] [-y] "output"
```

*Note : Things in brackets [] are optionnal.*

You'll have a simple framerate change, with a possible loss of input frames. **And, it's especially what you don't want to get.**

---

To have a framerate change without a loss of input frames, you'll have to use a **video filter**.

The **tblend** filter *blends successive frames*. It is the filter to use if source framerate is an integer multiply of destination framerate (eg : 60→30, 75→15, 75→25, ...)

```
ffmpeg -i "input" -vf tblend=all_mode=average [video encoding options...] -r outputframerate⁽¹⁾ [-y] "output"
```

⁽¹⁾ If haven't tested this filter myself, and I'm sure the output framerate must be set somewhere. The tblend filter has no fps parameter. Maybe it just blends 2 successive frames ? You should check this point, and make some tries ?

---

There exists another framerate changer, more adapted to be used with any i/o framerates :

**minterpolate** : *Frame rate conversion using Motion Interpolation.*

So, type :

```
ffmpeg -i "input" -vf minterpolate=fps=outputframerate [video encoding options...] [-y] "output"
```

The other minterpolate parameters have good enough defaut values, to make sure a good blend. Check them with a

```
ffmpeg -help filter=minterpolate
```

If you want to add some parameters in the minterpolate chain, you'll have to use a ':' as parameter separator.
Let's say you want to use *motion interpolation mode* = blend, instead of the default *motion compensated interpolation* (mci), type :

```
ffmpeg -i "input" -vf minterpolate=fps=outputframerate:mi_mode=blend [video encoding options...] [-y] "output"
```

If you want to use many videos filters, you must not chain -vf options. The last one will override the ones before. You must (as ':' for filter parameters) use ',' as filters separator. Ex :

```
ffmpeg -i "input" -vf minterpolate=fps=outputframerate:mi_mode=blend,filter2=param1=value1:param2=value2[...] [video encoding options...] [-y] "output"
```

The order of given filters are important.

---

Things have been done with

ffmpeg version 3.2.14-1~deb9u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers

Comment: ffmpeg -i "input" -vf tblend=all_mode=average [video encoding options...] -r outputframerate⁽¹⁾ [-y] "output"

This one actually is really good. Much better than minterpolate.

Answer (score 2):

Specifically for blending between frames in a time lapse to give a really high quality almost blur between the frames you can use `tblend=average`.

This is what I ended up using and provides an incredibly soft, smooth look to my time lapse videos:

```
ffmpeg -i in_video.mp4 -vf "tblend=average,setpts=0.05*PTS" -r 60 -crf 2 -an out_video.mp4
```

Or, for your use case:

```
ffmpeg -i in_video.mp4 -vf "tblend=average,setpts=0.5*PTS" -r 30 -crf 2 -an out_video.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

The most generic solution uses `tmix`:

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -vf tmix=frames=60/30 -r 30 ...
```

Where 60 is your input framerate and 30 your output.

### Background

The tmix video filter takes every input frame and averages it with its follower. At that point, you have a 60fps blurry stream. The `-r 30` subsamples that by selecting every other frame (and making it last twice as long), which leaves you with the desired result.

### Nit picking

Technically speaking this only works if your ratio is an integer (e.g. 50/25, 60/20, but not 60/24). If you *really* want to be precise, you could go from 60->24 (=2.5 source frames per output frame) by e.g. weighting a middle frame at 100% and both its neighbours at 75%, for a total of 2.5:

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -vf 'tmix=frames=3:weights=75 100 75' -r 25 ...
```

(Although I'm not sure why you would bother.)

### Sources

- https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#tmix
- https://video.stackexchange.com/a/34806

Thanks to Ian for the link and Max for the answer.